# Getting the sizeOf(a flatbuffers Table)

Tags: flatbuffers

I am using Flatbuffers with C++. I would like to create an array of bytes in a struct that is the size of the generated table (I am sending the contents as a payload for a NanoMSG message).

How does one do a sizeof(table)?

```
#include "pnt_generated.h"

struct packetStruct {
    Topics topic;
    int payloadSize;
    uint8_t payload[sizeof(pnt)];
};
```

does not work directly.

Comment: Perhaps this has some info on that https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flatbuffers/7wuLsfjI3u8

Comment: In C++ you cannot declare variable size arrays (a FlatBuffer is not a fixed size known ahead of time).
Note that you can create size prefixed buffers in FlatBuffers. So rather than trying to wrap a FlatBuffer in your own struct, you can use FlatBuffers for all of it.

Comment: @Aardappel I need to wrap it in a packet, since I am using a variant of ZeroMQ to publish it on the net, and the first bytes of the packet are the channel/topic. The rest is the payload which is Flatbuffers.

Comment: can reserve a std::vector instead of array.. 
 struct packet {  Topics topic; int pSize;  std::vector<uint8> payload(sizeof(pnt)); }

Comment: That does not help one get a contiguous memory block with the channel topic as the first bytes

Comment: Well it looks like no one has a better Idea for me to use a fixed size #define PayloadMax 256, then declary payload as uint_t[PayloadMax] and check in the builder if I exceed the size I don't expect bigger than 256, I don't think this will be a problem. And I am only sending the actuall size (int payloadsize) so what can get hurt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that Flatbuffers dynamically sets the size (in my case of the payload). And no one has a better idea, I am creating a fix sized payload in the struct, and then checking to see if I exceed that:

```
#define PayloadMax 256
#include "pnt_generated.h"

struct packetStruct {
    Topics topic;
    int payloadSize;
    uint8_t payload[PayloadMax];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of your payload from the bufferbuilder:

    `flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder(1024);

    auto l = CreateLogEvent(builder, builder.CreateString("INFO"), builder.CreateString("main.c"), builder.CreateString("Test Log Entry"));
    FinishLogEventBuffer(builder, l);
    auto ptr = builder.GetBufferPointer();
    auto size = builder.GetSize();`

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden feature in flatbuffers (prefixSize): https://flatbuffers.dev/class_flat_buffers_1_1_flat_buffer_builder.html#a425ab2bd13a0e4331a7190ec2d17c3b2

Or you might just use a different protocol.